# SAS proc report the split symbol is not working on "compute before" statement

Tags: split, sas, proc-report

I tried to output rtf, the first column is the classification, subgroup and level names. I concatenated classfication and subgroup together with the split symbol '~' into the variable 'cat' and I was expecting the they been output in two rows (shown in picture). But seems the split symbol did not split the classification and subgroup into two rows. It just shows like 'Class1~ subgroup1' in the output.

Is there any way to split the row in the compute statement in proc report?

```
    proc report data=final nowd nocenter headline headskip  missing split='~' spacing=0; 
      column  ( ord  cat subord header c1 c2 c3;

      define ord      / order noprint;
      define cat      / order noprint f=$100.;
      define subord   / order noprint;
      define header   / display  "Class~ Level~  Criterion" width=70 left flow;
      define c1       / display "n" width=12 center flow spacing=0;   
      define c2       / display "n" width=12 center flow spacing=0; 
      define c3       / display "n" width=12 center flow spacing=0; 

      compute before cat;
      line @1 cat $100.;
      endcomp;

     break after ord / skip;
run;
```

[The output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSK5f.jpg)

Comment: See what happens if you separate quote strings.
 define header   / display  "Class" "Level" "Criterion" width=70 left flow;

Comment: 'header' variable is good, what I want to split is 'cat' variable

Answer (score 0):

`split` only works in either column headings, or in the listing destination.  You would have to add line breaks yourself, perhaps using ODS ESCAPECHAR, or shrink the column to force it to split.

See [this question on communities.sas.com ("PROC REPORT Split")](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Proc-Report-split/td-p/68006) for example.